# What is the valid syntax for a KMS Key Policy to avoid MalformedPolicyDocument errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an AWS KMS Key Policy and have been plagued trying to get Cloudformation to accept the key policy.  Everything I have been able to find and read says this policy should be valid and the syntax is correct as it runs, but returns **MalformedPolicyDocumentExceptionnull (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400;**

Has anyone else run into this, if so, any thoughts or suggestions on how I can resolve the errors?  I've been stuck and banging my head on this one and can't see what I'm missing and my google-fu is failing me.

Code Snippet:

```
SnowflakeProdKMS:
Type: AWS::KMS::Key
Properties:
  Description: KMS key used by Snowflake to encrypt/decrypt data stored in s3
  Enabled: True
  EnableKeyRotation: False
  KeyPolicy:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Id: key-default-1
    Statement:
      - Sid: Enable IAM User Permissions
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS: 
            - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root
        Action: 
          - kms:*
        Resource: '*'
      - Sid: Enable AWSAdminRole to have full permissions to KMS key
        Effect: Allow
        Principal: 
          AWS: 
            - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:/role/AWSAdminRole
        Action: kms:*
        Resource: '*'
      - Sid: Allow use of the key by other roles
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS: 
            - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/AWSAdminRole
            # - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/SnowflakeAccessRole
        Action: 
          - kms:Encrypt
          - kms:Decrypt
          - kms:ReEncrypt
          - kms:GenerateDataKey
          - kms:DescribeKey
        Resource: '*'
      - Sid: Allow attachment of persistent resources
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS: 
            - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/AWSAdminRole
            # - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/SnowflakeAccessRole
            - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root
        Action: 
          - kms:CreateGrant
          - kms:ListGrants
          - kms:RevokeGrant
        Resource: '*'
        Condition: 
          Bool: 
            - kms:GrantIsForAWSResource: 'true'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much trial and error and reaching out to other partners I found the solution for the above issue.

The Condition on snippet above was incorrect and should have been formatted as follows:

```
Condition: 
          Bool: 
            "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": true
```

Once changed to this the policy went in without issue.